# Slick slider is not working while AJAX call using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a slick slider. While I'm calling a HTML part which have slick slider using AJAX call it is not working. I've mentioned my code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var year = $("#year").val();

        if(year == 'all'){


            $.ajax({
              method: 'post',
              url: 'helpData.php',
              data: {year:year},
              success: function(data){
                $("#helpData").html(data);
              }
          });
        }
    });
```

This is an AJAX call.

```
if ($(this).is(".slider3")){
      $(this).slick({
        dots: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:1500,
    prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false,
      });
    }
```

This code is for slick slider which is in another JS file which I already included.

```
<?php 
        foreach ($helpData as $hdata) { 
                    $heData = $help->getAllImg($hdata->heid); 
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="onePost">
                <div class="mySlider slider3">
                    <?php foreach( $heData as $himg ){ ?>
                    <div class="bannerSlider">
                        <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/img/help/<?php echo $himg->photo;  ?>" class="img-responsive otherImages" />
                    </div>
                    <?php  } ?>
                </div>
                <a href="highlightpost.php?id=<?php echo $hdata->heid; ?>">
                    <p class="photoCaption">
                        <?php echo $hdata->title; ?>
                    </p>
                </a>
                <p style="float: right;">
                    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></a>
                </p>

            </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

This is my `helpData.php` code which is called using AJAX.

Comment: Please note that Code-Snippets are only eligible for HTML, CSS and JavaScript (Core JS, not any frameworks) here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php

$html='';

foreach ($helpData as $hdata) {
    $heData = $help->getAllImg($hdata->heid);
    $html .=     '<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="onePost">
            <div class="mySlider slider3">';
   foreach ($heData as $himg) { 
       $html .='<div class="bannerSlider">
                        <img src="'.SITE_URL.'/img/help/'.$himg->photo.'" class="img-responsive otherImages" />
                    </div>';
    }
     $html .='</div>
            <a href="highlightpost.php?id='.$hdata->heid.'">
                <p class="photoCaption">'.$hdata->title.'</p>
            </a>
            <p style="float: right;">
                <a href=""><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></a>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>';
}

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: This is not working I want to know what is the problem while AJAX Call

Comment: print the html in php file using echo, make a string of html

Comment: please try again

Comment: Not Working..!!